# cspade function in arulesSequences throws connection error

Tags: r

I am using `arulesSequences` R library. This part of the code works fine:

```
x <- read_baskets(con = system.file("misc", "zaki2.txt", package = "arulesSequences"), info = c('sequenceID', 'eventID', 'SIZE', 'items'))
```

The `zaki2.txt` is located in

> C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\arulesSequences\misc

However, when I run the following code:

```
s1 <- cspade(x, parameter = list(support = 0.1, maxsize = 1, maxlen = 1), control = list(verbose = TRUE))
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
      3. file(con, "r") 
      2. read_spade(con = out, labels = itemLabels(data), transactions = if (control@tidLists) data, class = class) 
      1. cspade(x, parameter = list(support = 0.1, maxsize = 1, maxlen = 1), control = list(verbose = TRUE))
```

I just wonder why this connection problem occurs. I gave full access controls to this folder (I am using Windows 10), but still receiving the same error. Any help?

**UPDATE**

I found further details regarding the error. I checked this folder, and it seems that there is no *.out file in the directory.

```
reading sequences ...cannot open file 
'C:\Users\ERKANE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpohPsWy\cspade3894f1b4b9f.out': No 
such file or directoryError in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you did not get write permission to the temporary folder "C:\Users\ERKANE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpohPsWy".

You can run R.exe as an administrator instead of Rstudio, or delete the read-only attribute of the temporary folder.

Comment: well, then why `write.csv(mtcars,paste(tempdir(),"mtcars.csv",sep="\\"))` works fine?

Comment: Sorry, my explanation for this problem is wrong, But Rgui.exe can successfully execute cspade().

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just give the full path to the file?

Try printing the warnings - they probably mention a file not found.

Do set `mustWork=T` if you require the file.

What is the output of

```
fn <- system.file("misc", "zaki2.txt", package = "arulesSequences", mustWork=T)
```

And

```
fn2 <- system.file("misc/zaki2.txt", package = "arulesSequences", mustWork=T)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! Both code prints the path correctly. Actually, I do not have problem here. After I obtained the `x` variable, I get error when I put it  in `cspade`. I have no idea why I get a connection error in `cspade` since I am not doing any file operation. It starts outputting some results but then these results suddenly disappears and the error is shown.

Answer (score 3):

Did you remember to sort the data by sequenceID and eventID as required by cSPADE?

```
x <- x[order(x$sequenceID, x$eventID), ]
```

Answer (score 3):

`cspade` uses temporary files and numerous system calls. The help page says:

```
Temporary files may not be deleted until the end of the R session if the call is interrupted. 

The current working directory (see getwd) must be writable.
```

There are a number of locations where it writes files, eg this part of the code:

```
exe <- "bin"
if (.Platform$r_arch != "") 
    exe <- file.path(exe, .Platform$r_arch)
exe <- system.file(exe, package = "arulesSequences")
file <- tempfile(pattern = "cspade", tmpdir)
on.exit(unlink(paste(file, "*", sep = ".")))
```

The error suggests that the problematic location is `out`, which is defined as:

```
out <- paste(file, "stdout", sep = ".")
```

So I suspect it might be an issue with the temporary directory created at the start of the `cspade` call. You might want to set a directory for it to use explicitly, for instance if you have created a `cspadetmp` directory in your home directory:

```
cspade(x, parameter = list(support = 0.1, maxsize = 1, maxlen = 1),
  control = list(verbose = TRUE), tmpdir="~/cspadetmp")
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! well, I set the working directory. But, `arulesSequences` still uses its' default directory. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use the parameter in the `cspade` call?

Comment: Here is the call `cspade(x, parameter = list(support = 0.1, maxsize = 1, maxlen = 1), control = list(verbose = TRUE))`. But, the problem is the `read_baskets` call do not read the files from the directory that I set with `setwd`. It reads the files from the default library directory. `setwd` has not changed it for some reason.

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it clearer on how to set the cspade temporary directory. It looks like you are having some issues with temporary directories created via `tempdir()` which may be due to how Windows 10 deals with permissions.

Comment: You can test if it works with `write.csv(mtcars,paste(tempdir(),"mtcars.csv",sep="\\"))`

Answer (score 0):

If your gui is RStudio, not Rgui.exe, and you encounter the "cannot open..." error -

this did **NOT** work:

```
library(arulesSequences)
data(zaki)
s <- cspade(zaki, parameter = list(support = 0, maxsize = 1, maxlen = 1), control   = list(verbose = TRUE))
# parameter specification:
# support : 0
# maxsize : 1
# maxlen  : 1
# 
# algorithmic control:
# bfstype  : FALSE
# verbose  :  TRUE
# summary  : FALSE
# tidLists : FALSE
# 
# preprocessing ...CONF 4 9 2.7 2.5
# MINSUPPORT 1 4
# MINMAX 1 4
# 1 SUPP 4
# 2 SUPP 4
# 3 SUPP 1
# 4 SUPP 2
# 5 SUPP 1
# 6 SUPP 4
# 7 SUPP 1
# 8 SUPP 1
# numfreq 8 :  0 SUMSUP SUMDIFF = 0 0
# EXTRARYSZ 1232896
# OPENED C:\Users\lukeA\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6Ncns7\cspade1b8c67e92f8e.idx
# OFF 9 54
# Wrote Offt 0.00200415
# BOUNDS 1 5
# WROTE INVERT 0.000996828
# Total elapsed time 0.0100021
# 1 partition(s), 0 MB [0.12s]
# mining transactions ...MINSUPPORT 1 out of 4 sequences
# 1 -- 4 4 
# 2 -- 4 4 
# 3 -- 1 1 
# 4 -- 2 2 
# 5 -- 1 1 
# 6 -- 4 4 
# 7 -- 1 1 
# 8 -- 1 1 
# NA MB [0.13s]
# reading sequences ...Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
# In addition: Warning message:
#   In file(con, "r") :
#   cannot open file 'C:\Users\lukeA\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6Ncns7\cspade1b8c67e92f8e.out': No such file or directory
```

And this presumably **DID** work:

```
library(arulesSequences)
data(zaki)
old_gui <- .Platform$GUI
unlockBinding(".Platform", env =  as.environment('package:base'))
.Platform$GUI <<- "Rgui"
s <- cspade(zaki, parameter = list(support = 0, maxsize = 1, maxlen = 1), control   = list(verbose = TRUE))
# 
# parameter specification:
# support : 0
# maxsize : 1
# maxlen  : 1
# 
# algorithmic control:
# bfstype  : FALSE
# verbose  :  TRUE
# summary  : FALSE
# tidLists : FALSE
# 
# preprocessing ... 1 partition(s), 0 MB [0.14s]
# mining transactions ... 0 MB [0.11s]
# reading sequences ... [0.03s]
# 
# total elapsed time: 0.28s
.Platform$GUI <<- old_gui
lockBinding(".Platform", env =  as.environment('package:base'))
```